# Improve compiling speed in VS project using C++ Boost Libraries

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, boost

I have just started using Boost 1.36. These libraries would be very useful in reducing the amount of code needed in the unmanaged C++ software project that I am working on.

However when I tried to used these libraries my compile times increased ten fold. This would pretty much offset the productivity gains I would receive by using the library.

I am using a 3GHz Intel Dual Core with 2GB of RAM and VS 2003.

There is a snippet of the code that I added.

```
#include "boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp"   
#include "boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp"  
#include "boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp"  

typedef ublas::bounded_matrix <long double,NUM_OF_COLUMNS,NUM_OF_CATEGORIES,ublas::row_major> Matrix;  
typedef ublas::bounded_vector <long double,NUM_OF_COLUMNS> Vector;
```

`void Print(const Matrix& amount)

{`

```
Vector total;

total.clear();
for (int category = 0; category < NUM_OF_CATEGORIES; category++)
{
    PrintLine(ublas::row(amount, category));
    total += ublas::row(amount, category);
}

PrintLine(total);
```

}

Is the problem with VS 2003?
I know that VS 2008 is faster but upgrading is going to be a hard sell.
Is it just that Boost is optimized for fast run times not fast compile times?
Am I just using the Boost Library in a sub-optimal manner?
Or am I just using the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using precompiled headers? That is including the boost headers in StdAfx.h or whatever header file you use for precompiled headers?

Comment: I personally don't find that precompiled headers help speed up development. They're great if you're just building something, but if you're changing things in header files then they don't always actually speed things up. For this reason I tend to have a non precompiled header build for developing....

Comment: That depends which headers you add. If you add headers from your code then sure, it will make it worse since it forces a rebuild on each header change. But library headers (such as boost) don't normally change. Using pre-compiled for the Qt library headers in our app reduced compile time by 30-40%

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/)? It will allow you to distribute your build on multiple computers. I have seen it used successfully.